# REPLACE INTO causing deadlock

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

I am running into an error `1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'`

I am running mySQL 8 on an AWS backed RDS instance.

I am simply running the SQL: `REPLACE INTO table SELECT * from other_table;"`

Is there any way to debug this or work out how to fix it, I was under the impression that this is a fairly generic sql command.

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: Nope, there are not

Comment: A deadlock requires another transaction to have locked something, a single query cannot deadlock itself. You can debug it by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, it has a "deadlock" section which will list the other transaction(s) and the problematic locks. Please add this part to your question.